# how to echo everything before returning false?

Tags: php

How do I how to echo everything before returning false?

For example (pseudo-code):

```
$condition1 = TRUE;
$condition2 = TRUE;

      if($condition1)
      {
        echo "Hello World";
        return false;
      }
      if($condition2)
      {
        echo "Hello America";
        return false;
      }

      if($condition3)
      {
        echo "Hello you";
        return true;
      }
```

I want to to print "Hello World" **AND** "Hello America" before returning false. How can I do this?

Comment: then return false at the end **only**!

Comment: the first return met .. produce the exit from your code   ... so if you want the two echo apply the return only at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below syntax.

```
  <?php
$condition1 = TRUE;
$condition2 = TRUE;
$condition3 = TRUE;
//Make by default $result true
$result = true;
if($condition1)
{
    echo "Hello World";
    //update $result to false
    $result =  false;
}
if($condition2)
{
    echo "Hello America";

    //update $result to false
    $result = false;
}


if($condition3)
      {
        echo "Hello you";
        //update $result to true
        $result = true;
      }

//return $result

return $result;


      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return `false` after both `if` blocks.

```
$condition1 = true;
$condition2 = true;

if ($condition1) {
    echo "Hello World";
}

if ($condition2) {
    echo "Hello America";
}

if ($condition1 || $condition2) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: but sometimes I want to return true if condition 3 is met

Comment: If you just have the two conditions, you could add another check after (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have not posted the code below both `if`. So I assume more code for the third case (both conditions are false).

I have 2 solutions for you:

```
if ( $condition1 || $condition2 )
{
    if($condition1)
        echo "Hello World";

    if($condition2)
        echo "Hello America";

    return false;
}

// ... more code
```

and

```
$abort = 0;

if ( $condition1 )
{
    echo "Hello World";
    $abort++;
}

if ( $condition2 )
{
    echo "Hello America";
    $abort++;
}

if ($abort)
    return false;

// ... more code
```